# The redux is giving "is not a function" error - redux sauce

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm using redux sauce. When I dispatch an action, it is giving me "_HelpRedux.default.request is not a function" error. Any help is appreciated. How can I make it right? I'm out of ideas. Thanks in advance

HelpRedux.js

```
import { createReducer, createActions } from 'reduxsauce';
import Immutable from 'seamless-immutable';

const { Types, Creators } = createActions({
  helpPostt: null,
  dashboardRequest: ['data'],
})

export const HelpTypes = Types
export default Creators

export const INITIAL_STATE = Immutable({
  fetching: false,
  data: null,
})

export const helpRequestPost = (state) => {
  return state;
}

export const request = (state) => state.merge({ fetching: true });

export const reducer = createReducer(INITIAL_STATE, {
  [Types.HELP_POSTT]: helpRequestPost,
  [Types.DASHBOARD_REQUEST]: request,
})
```

HelpScreen.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Text, KeyboardAvoidingView, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, Linking, Platform } from 'react-native'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import HelpRedux from '../Redux/HelpRedux';

class HelpScreen extends Component {

  tryLogin = () => {
    this.props.request(); //_HelpRedux.default.request is not a function
    //this.props.helpRequestPost(); //_HelpRedux.default.helpRequestPost is not a function
  }

  render () {
    console.log("help", this.props);
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.tryLogin}>
            <Text>abc</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    request: () => dispatch(HelpRedux.request()),
    helpRequestPost: (key) => dispatch(HelpRedux.helpRequestPost(key)),
  }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(HelpScreen)
```

.                                                                           .

Answer (score 0):

OK I made a mistake here. Instead of calling an action, I was calling reducer.

```
request: () => dispatch(HelpRedux.helpPostt()),
```

Comment: Hi ... My code is similar to yours. Do you maybe know why I get "state.merge is not a function" when the reducer executes ? Would really appreciate your help